# Map file showing world countries with US State detail for Mapbox and Power BI

Tags: geojson, mapbox, mapshaper

I am hoping to find any type of map file (geojson, shape file, etc.) that is a world map with countries, but for the United States, it shows the states. So the States can appear like countries for the US, and then all over countries.

Does anyone know if this exists or how I can create it?

In mapshaper I can add both geojson files (world map of countries, states in the united states) and get them to overlap, but I don't know how to make this my finalized product.

This is for use in Mapbox and Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

Shapefiles for world administrative boundaries can be downloaded for the whole world from: https://gadm.org/download_world.html. Choose the top-level boundaries (I think it is coverage_0) to show all  country borders.
Then you can download a separate shapefile for just the United States from the same site, and show the state borders in that. Alternatively you could use a filter to select lower-level boundaries from the entire data set.

Comment: Hi Leigh, I don't have any GIS program to do this. I wouldn't know how to proceed. I loaded it to mapshaper and it had too much detail

Comment: OK I misunderstood your problem. I now see that it is how to save a combined coverage (shapefile or other format) containing both the world admin outlines and the US State outlines. Sadly, I don't know Mapbox so cannot advise but someone will be able to help.